# Update product attribtue value in install script

Tags: php, magento, installation, magento-1.9

I try to update the value of an attribute for all products in all stores in my upgrade script like this:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();


$products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
foreach($products as $product) {
    $product->setUpRoundingMode(0);
    $product->setUpTargetValue(0);
    $product->save();
}


$installer->endSetup();
```

But I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getStoreIds() on a non-object in app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Abstract.php on line 257
```

I'm using Magento 1.9. Any ideas how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to to use the data upgrade api from magento. An tutorial can be found here:
http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/

Answer (score 1):

I find the answers here a little unhelpful, so here's my two cents after encountering this problem as well.

If you're using a **setup** script to save data using a Magento model, you're probably doing it wrong. You should be using a **data** script instead. As Vinai explains in [this gem of an article](http://vinaikopp.com/2014/11/03/magento-setup-scripts/), the difference is :

> Data setup script details deserve their own dedicated section or post.
>   All in all they work in a very similar manner to schema setup scripts. In a nutshell, the key differences are that they…
>
> - Reside below the data/ directory
> - Have a data- prefix before their file name
> - **Are executed after the app environment is set up, right before the front controller is dispatched.**

Therefore if you're using a setup script, e.g.:

```
app/code/local/You/Module/sql/your_setup_name/mysql4-upgrade-0.1.2-0.1.3.php
```

Then you should move it to a different folder location, e.g.:

```
app/code/local/You/Module/data/your_setup_name/data-upgrade-0.1.2-0.1.3.php
```

A quick summary of useful notes:

#### Use setup scripts for:

- Creating tables in the database
- Inserting data into the database using the Zend (or low-level Magento) ORM (`insert`, `delete` etc)
- Adding new attributes
- Modifying existing attributes

#### Use data scripts for:

- CRUD'ing data with Magento models

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the function anywhere in the code you provided.  I believe your error is separate of your install script. Something is triggering the function getStoreIds() any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, traced it back to the attribute `msrp_enabled`, saving it fails

however i switched to just save the attribute i actually want to change within the setup instead of the entire product, i'm guessing this is a bug in magento or you're not supposed to save entire products within the setup

```
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'my_updated_attribute');
```